# How to know driver names?

Tags: linux, drivers

Is there any general way to know the name of the driver of all the devices on a linux machine? For example, I want to know the name of my network interface driver and the name of my webcam driver. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For devices in `/dev` check the corresponding entry in `/sys/class/<device>/device/driver`. Here an example:

```
ls -l /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0/device/driver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2013-07-15 11:08 /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0/device/driver -> ../../../../../../../../../bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio
```

Now you know it's the `ftdi_sio`. The module can be found with `lsmod | grep ftdi_sio`.

Another way is to run `lspci -k`, which nicely tells you which modules are used for which device.

Comment: fwiw, `systool` is a generic tool for querying and printing sysfs information in bulk. It might be useful to work that into your answer. The `-D` option will cause matching devices to be printed underneath their respective kernel modules.

Comment: For example: https://dpaste.de/HPdCK/

Comment: @JoelDavis - is `systool` a standard tool? I didn't see it on any of my RHEL based boxes.

Comment: @slm yep it's an old 'un too, came out about the same time sysfs did, which was around 2004 or 2005 I think. It's installed with the `sysfsutils` package that doesn't get updated too often, though (which I take to mean the project has stalled). Not sure why the name is so different but a lot of the documentation I'm finding online seems to imply ambitious plans for the project that apparently never materialized.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this probably does what you want:

```
sudo lshw
```

Answer (score -1):

With this command you should find the name of your driver : `lsmod`

Comment: This will find the loadable module NOT necessarily the driver.  BTW, I did not generate the downvote. Remember a driver can also be contained in a kernel statically, and thus this command would not be helpful as it lists only modules.